# Firefox Plugin to highlight text and send to another person

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, highlighting

I downloaded a Firefox plugin a few months ago which allowed me to highlight text on a web page. It would also generate a unique copy of the marked-up page and store it somewhere in the cloud. A URL would be produced that allowed me to email the marked-up copy to somebody. However I forgot what the plugin was called after refreshing my system a few months ago. Does anybody know of any plugins which perform this task?

Comment: Why the -1, mystery person? People ask questions about plugins all the time. I answered my own question to help people out.

Comment: Still waiting, mystery douche

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: http://marker.to/
Very useful add-on, figured I'd share with the world